# Sudo rights without sudo auth

Tags: authentication

I'm making an Ubuntu x86 Retropie. So far I have been able to figure out how to modify the OS to get all the hardware working but being a Windows admin I'm a little out of my depth on this one.

Is there a way to add a user who already has sudo rights into a group where they are allowed to run commands that require sudo without authentication?

I get this is a security no-no but this is going into an arcade cabinet without network access so I'm not too worried there.

The reason for needing to make this change is because whenever I select an option in RetroPie that requires OS access (things like change audio output, configure controller settings, etc). The RetroPie GUI invokes Retropie-setup.sh which then promptly asks for sudo Auth which a joystick and buttons aren't exactly up to the task and I don't want to have to keep a keyboard attached to the cabinet.

Comment: see `/etc/sudoers` and the manual for it https://phpraxis.wordpress.com/2016/09/27/enable-sudo-without-password-in-ubuntudebian/

Comment: Thank you @Rinzwind. That was exactly what I needed.